# Create Excel instance for exclusive access

Tags: excel, com

I am using an Excel instance for automation for which I want to prevent any interference from any other application. Setting `Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests = False` seems to do 99% of what I want to achieve.

However, if the user inserts a chart in an Office application (say PowerPoint) the chart editor will use my instance of Excel. I assume it calls `GetObject(, "Excel.Application")`. So what I basically would like to do is to hide my Excel instance from a `GetObject` call.

Possibly, embedding the Excel window would do the trick but I learned that this is neither recommended nor supported so what else to do? (Besides [creating two application instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761333/create-exclusive-word-instance).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this, Excel uses the running object table to register itself as explained in the link in the question. I don't see that embedding Excel would do anything to change this. So after all, there seems to be no better supported way than that explained under [Create exclusive word instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761333/create-exclusive-word-instance).